# Single page for Custom Post Type not found

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

I made a custom post type named `rt_test` in a WordPress plugin as follow:

```
register_post_type( 'rt_test',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Tests' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Test' ),
                'add_new' => __('New Test'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Test'),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Test'),
                'view_item' => __('View Test'),
                'search_items' => __('Search Test'),
                'not_found' => __('No Test found'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Test found in Trash'),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail' ),
            'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
```

And its data can be loaded via `WP_Query()` in `index.php` page of my theme. However, when I try to access the custom post type page (e.g. http://www.example.com/rt_test/test1/ ), it directs to WordPress's Page Not Found page.

From the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post) documentation, I know that I should make a `single-rt_test.php` file in theme's folder to allow the theme to know the content of this file should be used to load the post "test1".

However, after uploading the file to theme folder in parallel with `index.php`, the link ( http://www.example.com/rt_test/test1/ ) still redirects to Not Found page.

What did I miss?

FYI, the theme folder only contains:

- index.php
- single-rt_test.php
- style.css

Comment: Did you flush the permalinks structure by saving permalink again ?

Comment: The trick works ! But how come ? I didn't change Permalink structure since I build the plugin & theme.

Comment: because the new rewrite rules relating to the CPT are not created and written to the database until you `flush_rewrite_rules` which saving permalinks also triggers.

Comment: Can you post it as answer? I want to accept it, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Go to **Appearance » Menus** and add a custom link to your menu. This custom link is the link to your custom post type. If you are using SEO friendly permalinks then your CPT’s URL will most likely be something like this:

http://example.com/movies

If you are not using SEO friendly permalinks, then your custom post type URL will be something like this:

http://example.com/?post_type=movies

Make sure that your permalink structure matches up to the URL you are entering to try to get to the custom post page and check to make sure that your .htaccess file is writable, if not, you will have to insert the rewrite rules generated by wordpess on your own.

Comment: No, this is not for listing, it's for single post for the Custom Post Type.

Comment: The above trick is what I was trying to get you to do. Glad it worked for you.